# How to get a list view selection changed event from a data template WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, events, command

List view click is inconsistent with my listview in a data template. I have added an event setter to my list view because I would like to use the selection changed event of my list view to get the selected item of my list view and passed it to another function to be processed. I am temporarily using a message box instead of the function for testing. But when I select an Item the event only trigger some time I have a polling which happens every 5 seconds to update my list.

C#:

```
    private void ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonOtherMatchDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = sender as ListViewItem;
        if (item != null && item.IsSelected)
        {
            Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show("Test Event");
        }
    }
```

XAML

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <ListView  x:Name="lvExport"  ItemsSource="{Binding festItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding Selectedfest, Mode=TwoWay}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" >
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="test" Header="Data"  >
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="20*" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Image Width="75"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Source="Images/document.png"  Grid.Column="0"/>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                            <TextBlock  Text="Display Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left"     ></TextBlock>
                                            <TextBlock  Text="Twitter Handle"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="50,0,0,0"/>
                                        </StackPanel >
                                        <TextBlock Text="testdata" Height="80"></TextBlock>
                                        <Image Source="Images/document.png" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="79"></Image>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" >
                    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonOtherMatchDown" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Model:

```
class festViewModel : ToolViewModel
{
    public festItem _selectedfest;
    public festItem Selectedfest
    {
        get { return _selectedfest; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedfest != value)
            {
                _selectedfest = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Selectedfest");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to click an item twice to get the message box showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I would suggest that you create a userControl, and put everything under  into it.
Next Create a model class which will hold your Fest items.
Set the ItemsSource of the listview to be a Collection of Fest.
Set the SelectedItem to be of type Fest
I noticed that you are probably coding in the code behind of the file. Make full use of MVVM, and add this to the listView

```
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectionChangeCommand}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

In the view model, declare property SelectionChangeCommand of type ICommand.
Then in your SelectionChanged method, you can simply get the SelectedItem.
Do note that if you are going to be doing a polling every few seconds, in order to not lock up the UI, consider using Dispatcher.Invoke.

Comment: When you say create a user control do you mean for me to use code to create the list box? Or what you mean exactly? and for the dispatcher, I am using it for the polling already/ Do I also use it for selection change or with the function that I will call in the selection changed?

Comment: Yes. Create a user control under add new item --> WPF , User Control (WPF) That will create a empty user control. Paste your xaml inside. Do not really understand why you need to use polling to update your list every 5 seconds. If you implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your view model, any changes will be effected.

Comment: Thanks! I will Check out the user control. What the polling does is that it checks if my json file has been updated and passes it to my collection of objects in my view model. can I check for update from a url without polling?

Comment: Well technically thats not a wpf question, It depends on the url that you are going to check for. The relevant website which contains the url might have some APIs or RSS Feeds etc.